# Not seeing expected Aria tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wai-aria

I am trying to implement ngAria - have injected it in my module, Have the following html

```
First Name: <input role="textbox" type="text" ng-model="firstName" aria-label="First Name" required><br>

Employee: <input role="checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="isEmployee" arial-label="Employee" required>
```

I was expecting to see ngAria add aria-required, aria-checked and tabindex but it only adds aria-invalid. Is my understanding on ngAria wrong?

```
    "<input role="textbox" type="text" ng-model="firstName" aria-label="First Name" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" aria-invalid="true">"

    "<input role="checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="isEmployee" arial-label="Employee" required="" class="ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" aria-invalid="false">"
```

Answer (score 0):

NgAria automatically injects ARIA attributes for (some) default Angular directives.

This means for example: If you put `ng-disabled` on an element, it will inject `aria-disabled` at runtime.

**In your case:**

NgAria injects the `aria-required` attribute only if you add `ng-required` on your input. (By the way: It doesn’t matter if you put `required` or `aria-required` on your element. Both have the same effect on screen readers. So, your inputs are already correct marked as required)

The `tabindex` attribute only will be set automatically, if you put the `ng-click` directive on a by default, not clickable element. E.g.: `div` or `span`.

`aria-invalid` is put on the element because of the ng-model directive.

For a detailed overview of the supported directives and the associated ARIA attributes, have a look on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAria